# hspace, stretch and align

Tags: spacing

I want to align some equations. One equation has some text that I want pushed back to the margin. I tried

```
    \begin{align*}
    \text{Text:  } \hspace{\stretch{1}} \text{more text} x^2 &=y\\
    m^2 &= 2\\
    \end{align*}
```

which gives

```
                      Text: more textx2 = y 
                                     m2 = 2
```

but what I want is this:

```
Text:                       more textx2 = y 
                            m2 = 2
```

The hspace stretch combination works great on lines that aren't within an `align` block. I don't want to add a specific size (like `hspace{10em}`) since I may have to edit the line a bit later, and I do need to keep the pushed text ("Text") on the same line. Any ideas?

Comment: you're welcome :) can you turn your code snippet into a complete MWE- there are a few commands you've used that aren't obvious where they came from

Comment: I hope that helps. This edit has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will understand your needs better through a MWE. With `amsart` your needs will be met like this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % amsart doesn't need this.
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % Added to show frames, you may remove this in your file.
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{flalign*}
\text{Text:} && \text{more text  } x^2 &=y &&  \\
&& m^2 &= 2 &&
\end{flalign*}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using the amsart documentclass. Trying this solution gives me an error saying that falign* is undefined. If I include the [fleqn] option, it gives me errors until I toggle off all the ams packages. Is there a way to define falign*?

Comment: @Lex: This should still work with an `flalign*` environment (tested on [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com)) if you use `\documentclass{amsart}` (without `[fleqn]`) without loading the `amsmath` package.